# Extract number from string with Oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqltools

I need to create an Oracle DB function that takes a string as parameter. The string contains letters and numbers. I need to extract all the numbers from this string. For example, if I have a string like **RO1234**, I need to be able to use a function, say `extract_number('RO1234')`, and the result would be **1234**.

To be even more precise, this is the kind of SQL query which this function would be used in.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name, extract_number(column_name) 
FROM table_name
WHERE extract_number(column_name) = 1234;
```

QUESTION: How do I add a function like that to my Oracle database, in order to be able to use it like in the example above, using any of Oracle SQL Developer or SQLTools client applications?

Comment: You can use inbuilt function `regex_replace`, `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name,'[[:alpha:]]') from tbl`, at least you should search in Google, see this(https://community.oracle.com/thread/598281) oracle community provides some usefull ways

Comment: I could use a good example. I'm not good with Oracle

Comment: "I need to extract all the numbers from this string" - what should happen if the input string contains several numbers? E.g. what should your function return for the input '1234abc5678' ?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt, given the format of the values stored on that column, there is no need to consider this possibility.

Comment: Your example query seems to have errors, i.e. single quotes around `table_name` (and possibly also incorrectly around `column_name`). Also why would you want to have the extracted number also in the column list, when you already know exactly what it is, as you have specified it in the `WHERE` condition?

Comment: @ValiS: The goal of StackOverflow is not just to provide answers to the ones asking questions, but also for those questions and answers serving others with similar problems. For that reason it's beneficial for others that the question is clear and complete. If there are errors, omissions or anything is unclear, the questions should be edited, regardless if everything was later explained in comments or answers. That's one of the core purposes of the "[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32861256/edit)" option being there.

Comment: @ValiS: I'm not sure where this is coming from. My intention was not to question your expertise, but give constructive feedback (suggest improvements). I don't see how my comments have indicated my lack of experience (although I might not have shown here anything to prove I have it). Even if I was unqualified with Oracle DB, as you suggest, this is not relevant to what is expected from StackOverflow users. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) on why and how editing is beneficial.

Comment: @ValiS: No, it's not OK to use single quotes around table/column names in Oracle. Single quoted string is a string literal (or - under some conditions - a date literal), not an Oracle identifier (as table/column names are). It's usually the same in most (if not all) other SQL dialects, not just Oracle's. Maybe you meant double quotes? Which may be OK (but may not be OK, as unquoted and quoted may result in a different identifier). You may also be confused by how you may be constructing your queries in some PHP tools/frameworks (i.e. a single-quoted PHP literal becomes an unquoted part of SQL).

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [Oracle community post on What is the difference between single quote (') and double quote(")  ?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/978489) and this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f83b4de07f267f32e0f77b8206ee3cc) on how using single/double/none quotes with Oracle DB makes a difference.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You'd use `REGEXP_REPLACE` in order to remove all non-digit characters from a string:

```
select regexp_replace(column_name, '[^0-9]', '')
from mytable;
```

or

```
select regexp_replace(column_name, '[^[:digit:]]', '')
from mytable;
```

Of course you can write a function `extract_number`. It seems a bit like overkill though, to write a funtion that consists of only one function call itself.

```
create function extract_number(in_number varchar2) return varchar2 is
begin
  return regexp_replace(in_number, '[^[:digit:]]', '');
end;
```

Comment: I don't need to modify the sql query, I need that function that I can call

Comment: `REGEXP_REPLACE` *is* the function you would call to extract the digits.

Comment: However, I've added the function you can write to call `regexp_replace` for you.

Comment: Yup, Overkill is my other name. Thank you.

Comment: How to get the first number in column_name? Because your answer concatenates digits.

Comment: can some one tell me how to add a alias to the function regecp_replace after writing it

Comment: @ABHISHEK D: Are you looking for `select regexp_replace(column_name, '[^0-9]', '') as my_numeric_value from mytable;`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner ignore I got it!

Comment: the third arguments `, ''` for provided cases of `regexp_replace` function are redundant, where should be enough to use `regexp_replace(column_name, '[^0-9]')` or `regexp_replace(column_name, '[^[:digit:]]')`

Answer (score 10):

You can use **regular expressions** for extracting the number from string. Lets check it. Suppose this is the string mixing text and numbers 'stack12345overflow569'. This one should work:

```
select regexp_replace('stack12345overflow569', '[[:alpha:]]|_') as numbers from dual;
```

which will return "12345569".

also you can use this one:

```
select regexp_replace('stack12345overflow569', '[^0-9]', '') as numbers,
       regexp_replace('Stack12345OverFlow569', '[^a-z and ^A-Z]', '') as characters
from dual
```

which will return "12345569" for numbers and "StackOverFlow" for characters.

Comment: This still returns text (character type), not a number. The answer would also benefit from placing it in the example query which was shown in the question.

Comment: how to get 569 i.e., numbers from the last character?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, I only need first numbers in string:

```sql
TO_NUMBER(regexp_substr(h.HIST_OBSE, '\.*[[:digit:]]+\.*[[:digit:]]*'))
```

the field had the following string: `"(43 Paginas) REGLAS DE PARTICIPACION"`.

result field: `43`

Comment: easier way to extract the first set of numbers in a string can be select regexp_substr(h.HIST_OBSE,'[0-9]+','')

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for 1st Number with decimal as string has correct decimal places, you may try [`regexp_substr`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) function like this:

```
regexp_substr('stack12.345overflow', '\.*[[:digit:]]+\.*[[:digit:]]*')
```

Comment: This has a typo (the opening single quote around the text doubled) and still returns text (character type), not a number. The answer would also benefit from placing it in the example query which was shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**To extract charecters from a string**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name,'[^[:alpha:]]') alpha FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In order to extract month and a year from a string 'A0807' I did the following in PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
    lv_promo_code VARCHAR2(10) := 'A0807X';
    lv_promo_num VARCHAR2(5);
    lv_promo_month NUMBER(4);
    lv_promo_year NUMBER(4);
    BEGIN
    lv_promo_num := REGEXP_SUBSTR(lv_promo_code, '(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)');

lv_promo_month := EXTRACT(month from to_date(lv_promo_num, 'MMYY'));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_promo_month);
lv_promo_year := EXTRACT(year from to_date(lv_promo_num, 'MMYY'));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_promo_year);
END;
```