# how to extract only the number in a string / characters

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I have a table, in this table there is a column called parent_data, where there is a line with several characters and in the middle of them a number.

Exemple:

```
|PARENT_DATA|
{"orderERPNumber":1093710,"orderERPPosition":"P"}
```

I wanna know if there's a way I can do a query where I extract only the numbers.

The basic query:

```
SELECT PARENT_DATA FROM IONV_SYNC.IONVS_CRITICAS;
```

RETURNS:

```
{"orderERPNumber":1093710,"orderERPPosition":"P"}
```

So i want it to return only the number `1093710`.

Comment: You would use `regexp_replace` as [asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861256/extract-number-from-string-with-oracle-function)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like JSON to me. In which case you should use JSON functions to get the value out:

```
SELECT json_query('{"orderERPNumber":1093710,"orderERPPosition":"P"}', '$.orderERPNumber') FROM dual;
```

More information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-AEBAD813-99AB-418A-93AB-F96BC1658618) on json paths (the `$.orderERPNumber` expression I used) and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for extracting numbers from string

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetNumericFromString
(
  @stringValue VARCHAR(256)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @intValue INT
  SET @intValue = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @stringValue)
  BEGIN
    WHILE @intValue > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @stringValue = STUFF(@stringValue, @intValue, 1, '' )
      SET @intValue = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @stringValue )
    END
  END
  RETURN LEN(COALESCE(TRIM(CAST(ISNULL(@stringValue, 0) AS INT)),0))>0 then COALESCE(TRIM(CAST(ISNULL(@stringValue, 0) AS INT)),0) else 0 end
END
GO
```

Then :

```
SELECT dbo.GetNumericFromString(PARENT_DATA) FROM IONV_SYNC.IONVS_CRITICAS;
```